# quickInsertTags tag is not working in froala-editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, froala

I and using [froala editor](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#quickInsertTags) and want to `quickInsertTags` plugin feature in my froala editor.

As per [document](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#quickInsertTags), I need to include `quick_insert.min.js` to use `quickInsertTags`.

I have included this js file, but still it not showing option to insert `div` tag.

html

```
<div id="example"></div>
```

JS

```
var editor = new FroalaEditor('#example', {
      toolbarButtons: [['bold', 'italic', 'underline'], ['fontFamily', 'fontSize']],
      quickInsertEnabled: true,
      quickInsertTags: ['p', 'div', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6']
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6yv4c1d9/)

Answer (score 2):

> It looks like this option is not used because the editor is making use of the default block tags rather than using a custom list. It should be removed from there.

I looked around and found out that maintainers of froala-editor agree that `quickInsertTags` does not work, and documentation regarding the same is misguided and should be removed.

`quickInsertTags` doesn't work because they are using the already defined insert tags list in their codebase, and not the custom list that you are passing.

The github issue mentioning this, https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/1999

PS: Note that this issue is old, and it is possible that they added the functionality for the same recently, since the documentation should have been removed already. You should reach out to @stefanneculai on the above issue page.